# Adding values of dictionary on the basis of key

Tags: python

I have got a list of dictionaries like this

```
[{'format_id': '294', 'section_id': '2', 'type_id': '2', 'num_questions': '5', 'positive_marks': '4', 'negative_marks': '0', 'partial_marks': '0', 'user_id': '1', 'updated_on': '2019-9-6 11:16:01', 'section_instruction': '/ckfinder/userfiles/Instruction-Image/Main_Pattern_Test/Physics-Section-B.jpg'}
{'format_id': '294', 'section_id': '1', 'type_id': '6', 'num_questions': '20', 'positive_marks': '4', 'negative_marks': '0', 'partial_marks': '0', 'user_id': '1', 'updated_on': '2019-9-6 11:16:01', 'section_instruction': '/ckfinder/userfiles/Instruction-Image/Main_Pattern_Test/Physics-Section-A.jpg'}
{'format_id': '294', 'section_id': '2', 'type_id': '2', 'num_questions': '5', 'positive_marks': '4', 'negative_marks': '0', 'partial_marks': '0', 'user_id': '1', 'updated_on': '2019-9-6 11:16:01', 'section_instruction': '/ckfinder/userfiles/Instruction-Image/Main_Pattern_Test/Chemistry-Section-B.jpg'}
{'format_id': '294', 'section_id': '1', 'type_id': '6', 'num_questions': '20', 'positive_marks': '4', 'negative_marks': '0', 'partial_marks': '0', 'user_id': '1', 'updated_on': '2019-9-6 11:16:01', 'section_instruction': '/ckfinder/userfiles/Instruction-Image/Main_Pattern_Test/Chemistry-Section-A.jpg'}
{'format_id': '294', 'section_id': '2', 'type_id': '2', 'num_questions': '5', 'positive_marks': '4', 'negative_marks': '0', 'partial_marks': '0', 'user_id': '1', 'updated_on': '2019-9-6 11:16:01', 'section_instruction': '/ckfinder/userfiles/Instruction-Image/Main_Pattern_Test/Maths-Section-B.jpg'}
{'format_id': '294', 'section_id': '1', 'type_id': '6', 'num_questions': '20', 'positive_marks': '4', 'negative_marks': '0', 'partial_marks': '0', 'user_id': '1', 'updated_on': '2019-9-6 11:16:01', 'section_instruction': '/ckfinder/userfiles/Instruction-Image/Main_Pattern_Test/Maths-Section-A.jpg'}]
```

I want to add the product of 'num_questions' and positive marks of the same section_id and add it to another dictionary

for eg output of this list should be something like this

```
dict={'1':240,'2':60}
```

where 1 and 2 are the section ids
I have been stuck on this problem for quite some time. Can anyone help me how do I go on about it?

I have created a dictionary something like this

```
[{'section_id': 2, 'section_marks': 20}, {'section_id': 1, 'section_marks': 80}, {'section_id': 2, 'section_marks': 20}, {'section_id': 1, 'section_marks': 80}, {'section_id': 2, 'section_marks': 20}, {'section_id': 1, 'section_marks': 80}]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to do it ?

Comment: Is this is JSON data? You just copy-pasted input, without checking format. Show your efforts.

Comment: I have created another dictionary [{'section_id': 2, 'section_marks': 20}, {'section_id': 1, 'section_marks': 80}, {'section_id': 2, 'section_marks': 20}, {'section_id': 1, 'section_marks': 80}, {'section_id': 2, 'section_marks': 20}, {'section_id': 1, 'section_marks': 80}]

Answer (score 1):

Try with `defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict

res = defaultdict(int)

for item in list_dict:
    positive_marks = int(item.get('positive_marks', 0))
    if positive_marks > 0:
        res[item.get('section_id')] += positive_marks * int(item.get('num_questions'))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = [{'format_id': '294', 'section_id': ........},......]

d={}
for i in arr:
    sec_id = i['section_id']
    pos_marks = (int(i['num_questions']) * int(i['positive_marks']))
    if sec_id in d.keys():
        d[sec_id] = d[sec_id]+ pos_marks
    else:
        d.update({sec_id : pos_marks})

print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
my_dict = {}
for d in a: # Where "a" is the list of dictionaries you posted
    if my_dict.get(d['section_id']) is None:
        my_dict[d['section_id']] = int(d['num_questions']) * int(d['positive_marks'])
    else:
        my_dict[d['section_id']] += int(d['num_questions']) * int(d['positive_marks'])
my_dict
```

Output:

```
{'1': 240, '2': 60}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `collections.defaultdict`

**Ex:**

```
from collections import defaultdict


data = [{'format_id': '294', 'section_id': '2', 'type_id': '2', 'num_questions': '5', 'positive_marks': '4', 'negative_marks': '0', 'partial_marks': '0', 'user_id': '1', 'updated_on': '2019-9-6 11:16:01', 'section_instruction': '/ckfinder/userfiles/Instruction-Image/Main_Pattern_Test/Physics-Section-B.jpg'},
{'format_id': '294', 'section_id': '1', 'type_id': '6', 'num_questions': '20', 'positive_marks': '4', 'negative_marks': '0', 'partial_marks': '0', 'user_id': '1', 'updated_on': '2019-9-6 11:16:01', 'section_instruction': '/ckfinder/userfiles/Instruction-Image/Main_Pattern_Test/Physics-Section-A.jpg'},
{'format_id': '294', 'section_id': '2', 'type_id': '2', 'num_questions': '5', 'positive_marks': '4', 'negative_marks': '0', 'partial_marks': '0', 'user_id': '1', 'updated_on': '2019-9-6 11:16:01', 'section_instruction': '/ckfinder/userfiles/Instruction-Image/Main_Pattern_Test/Chemistry-Section-B.jpg'},
{'format_id': '294', 'section_id': '1', 'type_id': '6', 'num_questions': '20', 'positive_marks': '4', 'negative_marks': '0', 'partial_marks': '0', 'user_id': '1', 'updated_on': '2019-9-6 11:16:01', 'section_instruction': '/ckfinder/userfiles/Instruction-Image/Main_Pattern_Test/Chemistry-Section-A.jpg'},
{'format_id': '294', 'section_id': '2', 'type_id': '2', 'num_questions': '5', 'positive_marks': '4', 'negative_marks': '0', 'partial_marks': '0', 'user_id': '1', 'updated_on': '2019-9-6 11:16:01', 'section_instruction': '/ckfinder/userfiles/Instruction-Image/Main_Pattern_Test/Maths-Section-B.jpg'},
{'format_id': '294', 'section_id': '1', 'type_id': '6', 'num_questions': '20', 'positive_marks': '4', 'negative_marks': '0', 'partial_marks': '0', 'user_id': '1', 'updated_on': '2019-9-6 11:16:01', 'section_instruction': '/ckfinder/userfiles/Instruction-Image/Main_Pattern_Test/Maths-Section-A.jpg'}]

result = defaultdict(int)
for i in data:
    result[i['section_id']] += (int(i["num_questions"]) * int(i['positive_marks']))
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'2': 60, '1': 240})
```

Answer (score 0):

This could do it, provided you modify the format in your question to a list of dictionaries. Because in your question, the list syntax is not correct since the dictionaries are not separated by commas.

```
dictlist=[{'format_id': '294', 'section_id': '2', 'type_id': '2', 'num_questions': '5', 'positive_marks': '4', 'negative_marks': '0', 'partial_marks': '0', 'user_id': '1', 'updated_on': '2019-9-6 11:16:01', 'section_instruction': '/ckfinder/userfiles/Instruction-Image/Main_Pattern_Test/Physics-Section-B.jpg'},
{'format_id': '294', 'section_id': '1', 'type_id': '6', 'num_questions': '20', 'positive_marks': '4', 'negative_marks': '0', 'partial_marks': '0', 'user_id': '1', 'updated_on': '2019-9-6 11:16:01', 'section_instruction': '/ckfinder/userfiles/Instruction-Image/Main_Pattern_Test/Physics-Section-A.jpg'},
{'format_id': '294', 'section_id': '2', 'type_id': '2', 'num_questions': '5', 'positive_marks': '4', 'negative_marks': '0', 'partial_marks': '0', 'user_id': '1', 'updated_on': '2019-9-6 11:16:01', 'section_instruction': '/ckfinder/userfiles/Instruction-Image/Main_Pattern_Test/Chemistry-Section-B.jpg'},
{'format_id': '294', 'section_id': '1', 'type_id': '6', 'num_questions': '20', 'positive_marks': '4', 'negative_marks': '0', 'partial_marks': '0', 'user_id': '1', 'updated_on': '2019-9-6 11:16:01', 'section_instruction': '/ckfinder/userfiles/Instruction-Image/Main_Pattern_Test/Chemistry-Section-A.jpg'},
{'format_id': '294', 'section_id': '2', 'type_id': '2', 'num_questions': '5', 'positive_marks': '4', 'negative_marks': '0', 'partial_marks': '0', 'user_id': '1', 'updated_on': '2019-9-6 11:16:01', 'section_instruction': '/ckfinder/userfiles/Instruction-Image/Main_Pattern_Test/Maths-Section-B.jpg'},
{'format_id': '294', 'section_id': '1', 'type_id': '6', 'num_questions': '20', 'positive_marks': '4', 'negative_marks': '0', 'partial_marks': '0', 'user_id': '1', 'updated_on': '2019-9-6 11:16:01', 'section_instruction': '/ckfinder/userfiles/Instruction-Image/Main_Pattern_Test/Maths-Section-A.jpg'}]
newdict={}
for item in dictlist:    
    if item['section_id'] in newdict:
        newdict[item['section_id']]=int(newdict[item['section_id']])+int(item['positive_marks'])*int(item['num_questions'])
    else:
        newdict[item['section_id']]=int(item['positive_marks'])*int(item['num_questions'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that will do the job:

```
data=[{'format_id': '294', 'section_id': '2', 'type_id': '2', 'num_questions': '5', 'positive_marks': '4', 'negative_marks': '0', 'partial_marks': '0', 'user_id': '1', 'updated_on': '2019-9-6 11:16:01', 'section_instruction': '/ckfinder/userfiles/Instruction-Image/Main_Pattern_Test/Physics-Section-B.jpg'},
{'format_id': '294', 'section_id': '1', 'type_id': '6', 'num_questions': '20', 'positive_marks': '4', 'negative_marks': '0', 'partial_marks': '0', 'user_id': '1', 'updated_on': '2019-9-6 11:16:01', 'section_instruction': '/ckfinder/userfiles/Instruction-Image/Main_Pattern_Test/Physics-Section-A.jpg'},
{'format_id': '294', 'section_id': '2', 'type_id': '2', 'num_questions': '5', 'positive_marks': '4', 'negative_marks': '0', 'partial_marks': '0', 'user_id': '1', 'updated_on': '2019-9-6 11:16:01', 'section_instruction': '/ckfinder/userfiles/Instruction-Image/Main_Pattern_Test/Chemistry-Section-B.jpg'},
{'format_id': '294', 'section_id': '1', 'type_id': '6', 'num_questions': '20', 'positive_marks': '4', 'negative_marks': '0', 'partial_marks': '0', 'user_id': '1', 'updated_on': '2019-9-6 11:16:01', 'section_instruction': '/ckfinder/userfiles/Instruction-Image/Main_Pattern_Test/Chemistry-Section-A.jpg'},
{'format_id': '294', 'section_id': '2', 'type_id': '2', 'num_questions': '5', 'positive_marks': '4', 'negative_marks': '0', 'partial_marks': '0', 'user_id': '1', 'updated_on': '2019-9-6 11:16:01', 'section_instruction': '/ckfinder/userfiles/Instruction-Image/Main_Pattern_Test/Maths-Section-B.jpg'},
{'format_id': '294', 'section_id': '1', 'type_id': '6', 'num_questions': '20', 'positive_marks': '4', 'negative_marks': '0', 'partial_marks': '0', 'user_id': '1', 'updated_on': '2019-9-6 11:16:01', 'section_instruction': '/ckfinder/userfiles/Instruction-Image/Main_Pattern_Test/Maths-Section-A.jpg'}]

output={}
for d in data:
    section_id=d["section_id"]
    num_questions=int(d["num_questions"])
    positive_marks=int(d["positive_marks"])
    product=num_questions*positive_marks
    if section_id in output:
        output[section_id]+=product
    else:
        output[section_id]=product
print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a way

```
unique_section_id=Array.from(new Set(data.map((d1,i)=>{
    return d1.section_id
})))

output={}

for(i=0;i<unique_section_id.length;i++){
    output[unique_section_id[i]]=data.filter((d1,i1)=>{
        return d1.section_id===unique_section_id[i]
    }).reduce((d1,d2) => {
        return d1 + parseInt(d2.num_questions*d2.positive_marks)
    },0)
}
```